# ABRecordSetValue change isn't shown in people picker view after the change in Swift (perhaps change isn't committed?)

Tags: swift

I'm trying to update the various contact properties in Swift using ABRecordSetValue() but the simulator doesn't show the change in ABPeoplePickerNavigation.presentViewController() the next time I open it up:

1. Tap button to open the contact picker
2. Select a contact
3. Tap button to open contact picker again

Expected:
The contact in the simulator has the new first name I assigned

Actual:
Println shows the value appears to have been assigned, but in the view, the name has not changed

I assumed that ABAddressBookSave() would commit the change so I'm wondering if something else is needed to commit, or perhaps I need to somehow update the addressBook reference used for the people picker view controller to reflect the change?

First the view does the prompt asking for access to contacts, and then assigns a value to the var adbk:

```
var adbk : ABAddressBook!
var authDone = false

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !self.authDone {
        self.authDone = true
        let stat = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
        switch stat {
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            println("no access")
        case .Authorized, .NotDetermined:
            var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
            var adbk : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()
            if adbk == nil {
                println(err)
                return
            }
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(adbk) {
                (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
                if granted {
                    self.adbk = adbk
                } else {
                    println(err)
                }//if
            }//ABAddressBookReqeustAccessWithCompletion
        }//case
    }//if
}//viewDidAppear
```

Then a button bound to showPicker displays the people picker UI:

```
var person: ABRecord!

@IBAction func showPicker(sender: AnyObject) {
    var picker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController =  ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
}//showPicker
```

When the contact is selected, I try to update that ABRecordRef! "person" using ABRecordSetValue, which returns true and also the value in person for the firstName prop shows the new value, so I'm not sure what's going wrong:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) -> Bool {
    self.person = person
    println(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())
    var updateSucceeded = ABRecordSetValue(person,  kABPersonFirstNameProperty, "New First Name", nil)
    println("Did the update succeed? \(updateSucceeded)")
    println(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())
    ABAddressBookSave(adbk, nil)
    println(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())
}//navController
```

(lack of) progress update:
After much swearing at Apple, I finally got the build working on my iPhone 5 (had to change didSelectPerson to shouldContinueAfterSelectingProgram as former is iOS8 only and latter is iOS 7 and deprecated in iOS8)

The results are slightly different than the sim - while both ABRecordSetValue and ABAddressBookSave say they succeed, in the phone, the ABRecordCopyValue just AFTER the save returns the old, unchanged name.  In the sim, it returns the changed name but the UI doesn't reflect that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, though I have to admit I don't understand why the fix works.

Problem - I was running ABAddressBookSave against adbk, which doesn't work

Solution - run ABAddressBookSave against self.adbk

I've slightly updated the peoplePicker method so here's my latest:

```
//This method shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson only works in iOS 7.0 and is deprecated in 8.0, but the 8.0 method doesn't exist in 7.0 so using this to test on my 7.1 phone
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecordRef!) -> Bool {
    self.adbk = peoplePicker.addressBook
    self.person = person
    println(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())

    //Gets the recordId of a person such as 1,2,3,4,5.  Note this number may change if somone backs up their contacts from iCloud or something like that
    var pId = ABRecordGetRecordID(person)
    println(pId)

    updateFirstAndLastName()
    return false
}//navController

func updateFirstAndLastName(){
//Note this next line no longer works in Xcode 6.1 so I'm commenting it out and replacing error with nil
    //var error:UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>=nil

    var updateSucceeded = ABRecordSetValue(self.person,  kABPersonFirstNameProperty, "aa", nil)
    println("Did the update succeed? \(updateSucceeded)")
    //println("Error: \(error)")

    println(ABRecordCopyValue(self.person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())

    var addressBookSave = ABAddressBookSave(self.adbk, nil)
    println("Did the addressbook save succeed? \(addressBookSave)")
    //println("Error: \(error)")

    println(ABRecordCopyValue(self.person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeUnretainedValue())
}//udpateFirstAndLastName
```

I'll update if I learn the details of how self works and why this scoping works where my other class level var did not.